# Use JADE lib for multiprocessing

Tags: java, matrix, multiprocessing, multiplication, agents-jade

I had a task to develop efficient program for multiply matrices of sizes 1000000x1000000.
I was suggested to use JADE library.

Can anyone just tell me how to proceed using JADE and multiprocessing of 1-10 machines to multiply the matrice.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Jade tutorials](http://jade.tilab.com/doc/tutorials/JADEAdmin/index.html)?